# Как можно сделать так, чтобы текст 'responsive' был по центру экрана?

Tags: html, css, html5

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Site 1</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_first_labor.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="first_quarter">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="128" height="128" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-headphones" viewBox="0 0 16 16">                
            <path d="M8 3a5 5 0 0 0-5 5v1h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V8a6 6 0 1 1 12 0v5a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1V8a5 5 0 0 0-5-5z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
        
    <div class="second_quarter">
        <svg class = 'laptop' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="128" height="128" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-laptop" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M13.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V11H2V3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11zm-11-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 3.5V12h14V3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13.5 2h-11zM0 12.5h16a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-13A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 12.5z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="third_quarter">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="128" height="128" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-phone" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M11 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h6zM5 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5z"/>
            <path d="M8 14a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
            
    <div class="fourth_quarter">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="128" height="128" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-clock" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V9a.5.5 0 0 0 .252.434l3.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0 .496-.868L8 8.71V3.5z"/>
            <path d="M8 16A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm7-8A7 7 0 1 1 1 8a7 7 0 0 1 14 0z"/>
        </svg>

            
    </div>

    <h3 class="fifth">responsive</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    .first_quarter {
    position:fixed; 
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:lightblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .second_quarter {
    position:fixed; 
    width:50%; 
    height:50%; 
    top:0;   
    left:50%; 
    background:lightpink;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .third_quarter {
    position:fixed; 
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    background:lightgreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .fourth_quarter {
    position:fixed; 
    width:50%; 
    height:50%; 
    top:50%;   
    left:50%; 
    background:cornflowerblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .fifth {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MWmqerG так ?

Comment: Да, то что надо! Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```css
.fifth {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 class="fifth">responsive</h3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fifth {
  margin: 0 auto
}



 <body>
  <h3 class="fifth">responsive</h3>
</body>
```